# Angular2 code review - .map vs data=>{} on http post

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 2 app and would like some feedback on some code.
My question is where should the ***this.saveJwt(res.json())*** call be placed?
Should it appear in the ***.map*** or the ***data => {}*** ?

This function just gets a auth token from a server then saves it to local storage.

Any thoughts appreciated.

```
public getAuthToken(credentials: ICredentials) {

    let _authUrl = 'http://localhost:2116/api/authentication';

    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    this._http.post(_authUrl, credentials, { headers: this.headers })
        .map(res => { this.saveJwt(res.json()) })
        .subscribe(
        data => { },
        err => this.handleError(err)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use map to just convert data and then I won't need to worry about converting it inside subscribe.

This is good because a lot of times the subscription is done by another class.

```
this._http.post(_authUrl, credentials, { headers: this.headers })
        .map(res => res.json() )
        .subscribe(
           data => this.saveJwt(data),
           err => this.handleError(err)
        );
```

Notice that you don't need curly braces in fat arrow functions when there's just one statement.